# Filter data frame according to minimum value of one column

Tags: r

I tried this code, but the result is that it shows me only the name of the country with the lowest corruption level, but I want to show a dataset with two columns: one with the name of the country and the other with the corruption score (trust government corruption). The last column is missing. Where did I go wrong?

```
lesscorruption <- df$Country[which.min(df$Trust..Government.Corruption.)]

View(lesscorruption)
```

**Result**:

```
V1  
Indonesia
```

Column `V2` with the `indonesia Trust..Governement.Corruption` score is missing

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R:

```
df[which.min(df$Trust..Government.Corruption.), c("V1", "V2")]
```

Comment: I wrote this code but it doesn't work..  Error in `[.data.frame`(df, which.min(df$Trust..Government.Corruption.),  : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Can you provide the data frame in your question? Will make it easier to replicate the error.

Comment: If I do what you want to do on the inbuilt `mtcars` data, this works: `mtcars[which.min(mtcars$qsec), c("cyl", "disp")]`